# Ajax pass variable to PHP with GET

Tags: php, ajax

The variable `$pos` has no value after that the Submit button I pressed.

```
<?php
    $pos = $_GET['pos'];
    echo "<br><br>pos = ".$pos; 
?>

<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=us-ascii">
    <title></title>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js'></script>

    <script type='text/javascript'>

        $(window).load(function(){

            var position = 128;

            $('#submit').click(function(){
                    $.ajax({
                        type:"GET",
                        url: "ajax_test.php",
                        data: { pos : position },
                        success: function(){
                        //do stuff after the AJAX calls successfully completes
                    }
                });
            });
    });
    </script>

</head>

<body>
    <br>
    <button id="submit">Submit</button>
</body>
</html>
```

The web console in FF shows:

```
[12:41:55.027] GET http://somehost.com/ajax_test.php?pos=128 [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 187ms]
```

Comment: #submit is an input of type submit, correct? and it is located inside of a form, right?

Comment: $pos is not defined. only pos defined

Comment: You have to learn about HTTP protocol, what requests and responses are, and how to use them - everything will flow straight after that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<?php
   if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='GET' && isset($_GET['ajax'])){
    $pos = $_GET['pos'];
    echo $pos; exit;
    }
?>

<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=us-ascii">
    <title></title>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js'></script>

    <script type='text/javascript'>

        $(window).load(function(){

            var position = 128;

            $('#submit').click(function(){
                    $.ajax({
                        type:"GET",
                        url: "test.php",
                        data: { pos : position , ajax:1},
                        success: function(response){
                        document.getElementById('response').innerHTML ='pos='+response
                        //do stuff after the AJAX calls successfully completes
                    }
                });
            });
    });
    </script>

</head>

<body>
    <br>
    <div id="response">pos=</div>
    <button id="submit">Submit</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why mixing `$('#someID')` and `document.getElementById()` in the same code?

Answer (score 1):

Your code is correct, your just not using the result of your Ajax GET Request.

Try this in your success function:

```
success: function(data) {
   alert(data);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any errors in your code, except that you call your PHP script from your JavaScript code, and don't do anything with the output. The echo $pos output isn't used anywhere. Add this to your script:

```
success: function(result){
    $('#YourResultDiv').html(result);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't retrieve your variable from the AJAX call.

Ajax is async and you can't modify a php code which is already computed.

But you can insert your data with jQuery with `appendTo()` for example